# Extract titles and paragraphs from json file by HTML elements style with keys:value both

Tags: json, file, extract, paragraph

In a json file there are many titles and paragraphs and many fonts. I want extract all the titles and paragraphs with keys:value both of from json file and re-write in newJson file by using python.

In many places the 'Text' key is not in json file. I want write 'Path' And 'Text' both keys:values. which is present in the object or not
I trying to do but it can't happen.

```
import json
keyword = ("Path", "Text")
with open("structuredData.json", encoding="utf8") as f:
    json_dict = json.load(f)
    a=json_dict['elements'][1]['Path']
    b=json_dict['elements'][1]['Text']
with open("indra5.json", 'w') as f:
f.write(a+"\n" )
f.write(b+"\n")
```

[image]

its one screenshot I take and upload it. in way many lines in which I given sorter.
in that image I want to extract 'Path' and 'Text' both of with its keys:values

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, keep in mind that .json files have the format [{"key": "value"}, {"key": "value"}]**

```python
import json

with open("structuredData.json", encoding="utf8") as f:
    json_dict = json.load(f)
    with open("indra5.json", 'w') as f2:
        f2.write("[\n")
        for element in json_dict:
            f2.write("{\n")
            f2.write('"path":"'+element["path"]+'",\n')
            f2.write('"text":"'+element["text"]+'"\n')
            f2.write("},\n")
        f2.write("]\n")
```